# precision using SQL LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everyone i want to filter db records using LIKE but i need more accurate results
Im using MySQL: 5.1.61-log

**products**

- id
- name
- keyword

and a few records (updated, just added a url to illustrate)

```
1 | prod1 | https://www.site.com/?q=yellow whiteBLUEred
2 | prod2 | https://www.site.com/?q=yellow-and-green blue orange_black
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE keyword LIKE '%yellow-and-green%'
```

returns (1) row. and this is correct

but

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE keyword LIKE '%yellow%'
```

returns (2) rows but only one record have the keyword "yellow"

how can i fix this? the LIKE operator is the right for this situation?

thank you!

Comment: You have two rows where the keyword column contains yellow, so they both should come back.

Comment: It's working exactly as designed - using "like '%yellow%'" will return every record with the word yellow in it.

Comment: I take it you need something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE CONCAT(' ',keyword,' ') LIKE '% yellow %'` but you should redesign your structure.

Comment: yes, i know and that's exactly what i need to fix. the second record has the keyword yellow-and-green and not just yellow

Comment: But what if "Yellow" is the last keyword in the list. There will be no trailing space. Or if it's the ONLY keyword in the list, there will be no spaces at all. I agree with Martin Smith that you should redesign your structure. Maybe build a "keywords" table with one keyword on each row and a product ID to relate keywords to products.

Comment: You may get better precision with CHARINDEX/PATINDEX..  Just a Thought..

Comment: that keywords are just an example. in the real world the keywords will be urls with query strings and i need to search for keywords inside the url so, there will be no spaces and no commas (i should have put urls in the question, sorry for that)

Comment: @handsome - update your post to show examples that are more useful/real/explain what you _really_ want, please

Comment: Please indicate what database system (and version) you want to use this with, since this dramatically affects what SQL functions are available to you

Answer (score 1):

why not use:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE keyword LIKE '%yellow %'
```

If you've always got a space then include it in your query

To deal with other possibilities:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE (keyword LIKE 'yellow %' or keyword LIKE '% yellow %' or keyword LIKE '% yellow')
```

Comment: Please see new edit.  Should deal with most cases I can think of.

Comment: That will still match keywords like "green-and-yellow". I suggest `(keyword LIKE 'yellow %' or keyword LIKE '% yellow %' or keyword LIKE '% yellow')` to cover all the bases.

Comment: How will it match green-and-yellow now?

Comment: Both had the same thought :)

Comment: Yeah, I think it will work with a minor tweak. The first `LIKE` matches "green-and-yellow" if it's not the last keyword in the list: `%yellow %`. We want to match "Yellow" at the beginning, middle, or end of a list.

Comment: Sorry, one more. Should add one with no wildcards in case it is the ONLY keyword in the list: `OR keyword LIKE 'yellow'`.

Comment: I really like this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012382/precision-using-sql-like#comment29799185_20012382

Comment: @user623952 Yeah, that's pretty nice. Adding spaces to the search term eliminates the need for so many `ORs` in the query.

Comment: i don't think they want to match `yellow-and-green` bc they complain in the question about getting 2 rows back.  but who knows... read the most recent comment by OP up there.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
where keywords = 'yellow'
   or keywords like 'yellow %'
   or keywords like '% yellow'
   or keywords like  % yellow %'
```

This solves the problem where yellow might (or might not) be the first and/or the last "word" in the list.